# feel hard to understand this custom type definition in my case

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am learning typescript custom types, I see code like this:

```
type ErrorBrand<Err extends string> = Readonly<{
  [key in Err]: void;
}>;
```

And its usage :

```
function a<T>(
  T : ErrorBrand<'My parameter'>
) {
}
```

I completely get lost with this type definition, I hope someone could elaborate for me with my questions below:

1. Why the custom type is using `Readonly`? What are the benefits using it?
2. What is that inside the angle brackets of `Readonly`? I mean what's this syntax that an generic kinda angle brackets with an object in it `{[key in Err]: void}` ?
3. What is this `{[key in Err]: void;}`? An object with dynamic key `[key in Err]` and its type is `void`?   Could someone please elaborate it for me?

Comment: You can read more about the `Readonly` utility type here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#readonlytype

Comment: More examples here on mapped types https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know the name of that syntax, now I got it.